# Query to De-Duplicate

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I need to run a query to de-duplicate a DE based on the field Email. Email, however, is not the unique field. Two others that are unique are messing with my query.

I tried DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email
FROM MyDataExt
```

But that brings up an error because I don't have the two unique fields (col1 and col2).

I can't select in the FROM because MC doesn't recognize the parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM MyDataExt)
```

So, would anyone know how can I run this query to de-dup based on Email address? Note: I looked into data filters, but I don't see how that allows me to de-dup because it's requiring me to have the email contain/equal to something ect, which isn't what I'n going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a date column (or any other column you can use to group the email addresses) :

```
SELECT Email 

FROM

(SELECT
 Email
 ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rank

 FROM MyDataExt) x

WHERE x.rank = 1
```